# Is the receiver application specific to the sender application or we can use it in general?

Tags: chromecast

I've downloaded sender and receiver applications from GITHUB and try to run the same on my server. I've followed all the guidelines that are mentioned over there and on the developers site. But still i am not getting any result. I want to know that whether a receiver application is specific for the sender application or we can use any receiver application for my sender application provided that we use our application id that we got after publishing it on the Google Developers Console ?

If its not general.. can anyone provide a sender application and corresponding receiver application sample so that I can learn a bit. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only "sandboxing" of receivers happens in the Chromecast SDK Console -- when you publish an app there and it's assigned an appID, it will be available to any sender that calls that appID (or, if it's an unpublished app, any sender that you've whitelisted to call that appID). You'll want to check all the settings in the SDK console; if the app is unpublished, make sure you've put the right serial number in for your devices to whitelist them and make sure that your device settings have the 'send serial number' option checked so they know they're whitelisted. But there is nothing right now, by default, in the receiver code that could stop other senders from connecting.

This doesn't mean, of course, that you couldn't write an authorization layer into your receiver app to prevent non-authorized senders from connecting.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. But I am facing a bit different issue. I've downloaded the sender and receiver application from GITHUB but I am not able to play the videos using custom-receiver. So is there any possibility that I am not using appropriate receiver application for my sender? I mean a receiver and sender are specific to each other?

Comment: Generally speaking, they are independent of each other. If you've put the receiver on your server, given it an https address, and whitelisted your device for that receiver, then you can create any number of senders that use that appID (if the app is published, no whitelisting is necessary). The only time a receiver and sender are specific to each other is if the receiver code has an authorization layer where it expects some tokens or other messaging coming from the sender. IF your receiver from GitHub doesn't have that, then the problem is likely somewhere in the console setup.

Comment: Can you please provide an example for sender and its corresponding receiver application so that i can learn from it. I am getting bit confused. Thanks

Comment: I don't have one in particular, but here's the general idea. If you want to have only your sender be able to connect to your receiver, you must utilize the CastMessageBus object of the receiver and require that your sender pass a particular message to your receiver before it will start playing the media. The "HelloWorld" sample in the chromecast repository (https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome/) shows you how to set up custom messaging on the sender/receiver ends. The message it passes could just be a token, for example, that verifies the sender is authentic.